# how to make a horizontal sliding bar without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I am using `ionic` framework and don't to use `jQuery` .how to make a horizontal sliding bar without using jQuery.

Something like : [image: horizontal slider]

I tried following code:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="wide-as-needed">
        <a class="button inline-button">this is a button : 1</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 2</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 3</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 4</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 5</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 6</a>
</ion-scroll>
```

I took reference from : http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/HIuft

but on mobile, touch did not work in above horizontal area.

Comment: If you dont want to use jquery then try this link, it will help you -> http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

Comment: "but on mobile, touch did not work in above horizontal area." dont quite understand this sentence?

Comment: @AaronSaunders If I try to scroll screen by touching screen area which comes under `ion-scroll direction-x` , then scrolling did not work.

Comment: a codepen would be helpful here

Comment: @AaronSaunders Ihere is a codepen - http://codepen.io/vinay885/pen/jPgmzx  it contain a horizontal scroll of buttons , but problem is that  vertical scrolling does not work if screen scroll using that horizontal area. Please let me know if it is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this maybe.

```
<div class="range-slider" data-slider>
  <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: is there any css for solution?